# ocfs2 v1.6 for CentOS 5.5

Tags: ocfs2

does someone know how/where to get newest ocfs2 version 1.6 for CentOS?

from oracle site I was able to download only 1.4 . but this version hasn't a lot of features

as you can see , there is only 1.4

http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/files/RedHat/RHEL5/x86_64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OCFS2 page:

> OCFS2 1.6 is only available with the
>   Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel. Users
>   wishing to upgrade to the new release
>   must logon to the Unbreakable Linux
>   Network (ULN) and subscribe to the
>   Oracle Linux 5 Latest channel.

Looks like oracle is going to make you convert your kernel to their "new" Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel, or use a vanilla kernel with 1.6 compiled in. From the ocfs2 web page:

> The file system source code is
>   available with the mainline Linux
>   kernel that can be downloaded from
>   kernel.org. The file system source
>   code for the Enterprise kernels is
>   available from oss.oracle.com.

The ocfs2-tools source is available at http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2-tools/files/source/v1.6/ (No binaries for rhel5)

Comment: sucks... 
do you know another cluster FS with SElinux ,quota, acl support ?

Comment: You could try GFS2. It has extended attribute supprt, which means ACL and SELinux are supported.